# Fetching mysql row results as dictionary with Python Flask Mysql Cursor class

Tags: flask, flask-mysql

am trying out creating a web app using python flask framework. I've installed flask-mysql library to interact with mysql db. However, am having trouble getting rows as dictionaries rather than tuples. With the usual python-mysql library, it's a matter of adding "cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor," to my database handle.

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()
# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'user'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'mydb'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

mysql.init_app(app)
```

I've tried adding app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor' but that doesn't work. It instead works with flask-mysqldb from documentation [here](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Also am confused about flask-mysql and flask-mysqldb libraries, which one should I be using.

Comment: In your code i am seeing: `from flaskext.mysql import MySQL` while the example you are linking to states: `from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL`

Comment: flask-mysql uses flaskext.mysql import MySQL well as flask-mysqldb uses from flask.ext.mysqldb import MySQL, which is another point of confusion am seeking clarification

Comment: Ok, i did a bit of research but you should be referring to the new MySQL cursor dict classes, seen [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cursor-subclasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

i found other way to config the flask server in [flask-mysql](https://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)(don't confuse with flask-mysqldb),
you can do this:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import pymysql

mysql = MySQL()
mysql = MySQL(app, prefix="mydb", host="localhost",password='password', user="user", db="mydb", cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```